# how to disable a textbox?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html

how to disable a text box while loading the page?
**MY JS**

```
<script language="javascript">
        function enableDisable(bEnable, textBoxID) {
            document.getElementById(textBoxID).value = ""
            document.getElementById(textBoxID).disabled = !bEnable

        }
    </script>
```

**MY VIEW**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" onclick="enableDisable(this.checked, 'textBox')">Reason<br />
 <input type="text" id="textBox">
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to load it as disabled?

Comment: yep thats why i am in need of it

Comment: yes why not just set the `<input>` to have the attribute already set with `disabled` or for non HTML5 doctype `disabled="disabled"`

Comment: whats the code for html 5?

Comment: it is this for text input `<input type="text" value="" disabled>` HTML5 disabled attribute is just the word disabled :)

Answer (score 0):

Set it as disabled by default then use the window.onload event to enable it.

$(document).ready will fire when the HTML document has loaded but window.onload will wait until the entire page (images, scripts, etc) are loaded.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k14dgr30/2/

```
    document.querySelector('inout[type="text"]').disabled = true;

    window.onload(function () {
       document.querySelector('inout[type="text"]').disabled = false;
    });
```

Comment: Please don't use jQuery in an answer that is not tagged with that library.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript">
    window.onload =enableDisable(false,"textBox");

    function enableDisable(bEnable, textBoxID) {
        document.getElementById(textBoxID).value = ""
        document.getElementById(textBoxID).disabled = !bEnable

    }
</script>
```